# How to create solution in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, solution

I have to create website with business layer and data access layer. I want to have a structure like this.

Complete project inside a solution. So that to open a website and other projects, I have to open only the solution.

I tried like this, first I created on website and than added the projects to the website. but it is not coming as a solution. Please help

Comment: By chance are you using the express version? I don't believe express allows solutions, only projects.

Comment: @Brad Christie: I am using VS2008 professional edition

Comment: Then all you need to do is create a project (probably the website) and the solution will be generated with the same name. If you're picky about your solution name, make a new project with the name of the solution, then right click your solution in the tree and select "Add project" with your site/data layer/database project names. Then you can remove the default project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> 1. In Visual Studio, click File, point to New, and then click Project.
> 2. In the New Project dialog box, in the Project types pane, click Other
>      Project Types, and then click Visual
>      Studio Solutions.
> 3. In the Templates pane, click Blank Solution.
> 4. Enter the name of your project in the Name field, and then click OK.

Comment: Wow, didn't even realize you could make a blank solution. Interesting. +1.